# GitHub Collaboration Using the Shared Repository Model

Tags: github

Can someone provide me with the cheat sheet for GitHub collaboration for a team of two who want equal access/rights to the repo. I am confused as to the need to use forking which appears to make sense for a large open source project with dispersed devs but seeems like overkill when I and my partner sit 10 feet from each other.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you have a small team and want everyone to have access to the repo, you can just grant them collaborator permission in the repo's admin settings. Forking isn't required if your scenario doesn't require it. (Although forking can be useful, you're also partly right: if you have a small team and know all the other team members and don't mind giving them read/write access, there's no need to fork.)

Comment: Just so I fully understand. My partner is the owner/initiator of the private repo. I am the collaborator as far as GitHub is concerned. Do I fork the repo to boostrap the collaboration process? Clone? What.

Comment: If you have read/write access, you can just clone, and then push your changes back into it.

Answer (score 2):

the difference between *the fork and pull model* and *the shared repository model* could be explained by the Github.com:
(https://help.github.com/articles/about-collaborative-development-models/)

About collaborative development models
The way you use pull requests depends on the type of development model you use in your project.

There are two main types of development models with which you'd use pull requests. In the fork and pull model, anyone can fork an existing repository and push changes to their personal fork without needing access to the source repository. The changes can be pulled into the source repository by the project maintainer. When you open a pull request proposing changes from your fork's branch to a branch in the source (upstream) repository, you can allow anyone with push access to the upstream repository to make changes to your pull request. This model is popular with open source projects as it reduces the amount of friction for new contributors and allows people to work independently without upfront coordination.

In the shared repository model, collaborators are granted push access to a single shared repository and topic branches are created when changes need to be made. Pull requests are useful in this model as they initiate code review and general discussion about a set of changes before the changes are merged into the main development branch. This model is more prevalent with small teams and organizations collaborating on private projects.