# Set up git to push to another user's Github repo?

Tags: git, github

Let's say I'm `user1` and I have a Github account at `http://github.com/user1`. Naturally, I'd set up git locally as so:

```
origin git@github.com:user1/repo.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:user1/repo.git (push)
```

What would I do if I have fetch & push permissions to someone else's repo (let's say `user2`) whose repo is located at `http://github.com/user2/user2srepo.git`?

EDIT:
Sorry, everyone is right with their answers. I should have clarified that I used to have it set up as `origin http://github.com/user2/user2srepo.git` but I wanted to avoid being asked for user credentials every single time I pushed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub Collaboration Using the Shared Repository Model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454839/github-collaboration-using-the-shared-repository-model)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your github repos are both for the same codebase, you can add them both as remotes to your local repo:

```
git remote add otherusersorigin http://github.com/user2/user2srepo.git
```

Then use that alias whenever you need it:

```
git fetch otherusersorigin
git push otherusersorigin
```

To do this with no authentication prompt, set up SSH keys for your self according the standard GitHub instructions and get the other person to add you as a collaborator on that repo.

Comment: That's what I had before and it was working fine - I should have clarified in my original question that I wanted to set it up in a way that I wouldn't be asked for user credentials every single time I pushed.

Comment: Ah. In that case, set up SSH keys for your self according the standard GitHub instructions and get the other person to add you as a collaborator on that repo.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it's easier than I thought. Thanks to the help of @MattGibson and @eykanal in the comments, I realized that I could just set the remote as follows:

```
origin git@github.com:user2/user2srepo.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:user2/user2srepo.git (push)
```

The difference here being that the user is setup as `user2` and not my own username. I mistakenly thought I'd need to enter `user2`'s credentials, but that's not the case if I've been set as a collaborator on `user2srepo`.

For those interested, the command to set this if you already have the remote set is as follows:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:user2/user2srepo.git
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have write permissions to that repo, simply clone that repository and commit directly to it. You don't need to go through the forking process.

Comment: It's for work, which doesn't permit cloning to my own account.

Comment: You misunderstand; on your local machine, you should clone the repository from `user2`'s account. You shouldn't fork it, just clone it as though it was your own.